# Put subfigure labels inside figures using subfig package

Tags: subfloats

I'd like to put subfigure labels (a), (b), etc., at the top left corner of subfigures like the following figure:

[image]

I know there are some workarounds like [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127853/subfigures-with-number-inside-figure) (with `stackengine`) or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127900/moving-subcaptions-vertically) (with `subcaption`). However, I don't want to use `stackengine` unless there's really no way to do so, and REVTeX4 rules out the `subcaption` option. I therefore wonder if there exists a workaround specifically for `subfig` package (and potentially compatible with REVTeX4).

The following MWE provides an unsuccessful attempt to achieve the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=-10pt, position=top}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
    \subfloat[][]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \subfloat[][]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{abcd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is very similar to [Subfigures with number inside figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127853/5764). Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Werner, it did, but as I mentioned in the post, I'm looking for other possible workarounds because I'm not sure if the journal publisher accepts tex files which include the `stackengine` package.

Comment: @Werner, another reason I don't like the answer in [that post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127853/subfigures-with-number-inside-figure) is that I want LaTeX to take care the typeset, including subfigures. If I can pre-process my figure like the example shown in that question, honestly speaking I can also insert a subfigure label using external software. Then why bother to do that with LaTeX?

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd suggest writing your own macro to place the sub-figure numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxutil
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{10pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-2\baselineskip}{#2}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.45\linewidth}@{\quad}p{0.45\linewidth}@{}}
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{A)}{example-image-a} &
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{B)}{example-image-b} \\
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{C)}{example-image-c} &
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{D)}{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Once you have the image, you can print it in a box and extract its dimensions in order to use them to position the label.

The above macro `\subfigimg[<options>]{<label>}{<image>}` does exactly that. It inserts `<image>` with options `<options>` and imprints the `<label>` 10pt from the left and 2 baseline skips from the top of the image.

No packages nor tomfoolery. Just box manipulation.

---

Some added flair with string comparison for positioning...

pdfTeX introduced `\pdfstrcmp` for string comparison in [version 1.30](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2005-August/005913.html):

> `\pdfstrcmp{<a>}{<b>}` compares two strings and returns the strings "0"
>       if  equals `<b>`, "-1" if `<a>` is less than `<b>`, "1" if `<a>` is greater
>       than `<b>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxutil
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{xkeyval,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xkeyval,xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\sfp@hseplen}\newlength{\sfp@vseplen}
\define@cmdkey{subfigpos}[sfp@]{pos}[ul]{}% \sfp@pos
\define@cmdkey{subfigpos}[sfp@]{font}[\small]{}% \sfp@font
\define@cmdkey{subfigpos}[sfp@]{vsep}[2\baselineskip]{\setlength{\sfp@vseplen}{\sfp@vsep}}% \sfp@vsep
\define@cmdkey{subfigpos}[sfp@]{hsep}[10pt]{\setlength{\sfp@hseplen}{\sfp@hsep}}% \sfp@hsep
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setkeys{Gin,subfigpos}{pos,font,vsep,hsep,#1}% Set (default) keys
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{#3}}% Store image in box
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\sfp@pos}{ul}=0% UPPER LEFT placement of subfig label
    \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
    \rlap{\hspace*{\sfp@hsep}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-\sfp@vsep}{\sfp@font{#2}}}% Print label
    \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spacing
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\sfp@pos}{ur}=0% UPPER RIGHT placement of subfig label
    \leavevmode\usebox1% Print image
    \llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-\sfp@vsep}{\sfp@font{#2}}\hspace*{\sfp@hsep}}% Print label
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\sfp@pos}{lr}=0% LOWER RIGHT placement of subfig label
    \leavevmode\usebox1% Print image
    \llap{\raisebox{\sfp@vsep}{\sfp@font{#2}}\hspace*{\sfp@hsep}}% Print label
  \else% Assume LOWER LEFT placement of subfig label
    \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
    \rlap{\hspace*{\sfp@hseplen}\raisebox{\sfp@vsep}{\sfp@font{#2}}}% Print label
    \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spacing
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.45\linewidth}@{\quad}p{0.45\linewidth}@{}}
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth,pos=lr]{A)}{example-image-a} &
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth,pos=ll,font=\color{green!30!red}]{B)}{example-image-b} \\
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth,pos=ur,font=\LARGE]{C)}{example-image-c} &
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth,pos=ul]{D)}{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE adds the keys `pos`, `font`, `hsep` and `vsep` to the mix. In turn they allow for selecting the `pos`ition of the label, which `font` to use, the `h`orizontal `sep`aration and `v`ertical `sep`aration.

Comment: This is as awesome as another answer Werner! It's hard for me to decide which one I should accept :(

Comment: For those who don't want to use the `tabular` environment: the macro defined by Werner is compatible with the `subfig` package. Just pretend the whole `\subfigimg` object as if it were `\includegraphics` and do


`\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \subfloat{\subfigimg[width=0.45\linewidth]{(a)}{example-image-a}}\quad
      \subfloat{\subfigimg[width=0.45\linewidth]{(b)}{example-image-b}} \      \subfloat{\subfigimg[width=0.45\linewidth]{(c)}{example-image-c}}\quad
      \subfloat{\subfigimg[width=0.45\linewidth]{(d)}{example-image-a}}
    \caption{abcd}
\end{figure}`

Comment: is there a precise way to control the font size of the label?

Comment: @LeoFang: Yes; the label is argument `#2` in `\subfigimg{#1}{#2}{#3}`. So, add whatever you want before/around `#2` in the definition. For example, `\Large #2` would set the label in `\Large` font; `\textbf{\textit{#2}}` would set a **bold** *italicized* label...

Comment: Ahh, so simple! I was thinking about using `\vspace` and wondering why it didn't work...Thanks Werner!

Comment: Nice answer, and this helped me to save much space within my current paper. However, I don't understand the \rlap and tex magic stuff, how can I place the label in lower right, upper right or lower left resp.? I tried with \hfill instead of \hspace but with not luck. Thanks.

Comment: @math: I'll add an option that allows you to specify where you want the overlaid caption...

Comment: @Werner: if automatic coloring of the label (or caption) is easy to realize it would be awesome as well. If its not that easy, I will go with my solution, of defining a forth parameter handing over the textcolor. Thanks, this helped me a lot so far.

Comment: @math: See the updated answer which now adds 4 different keys for label placement/font/separation.

Comment: @Werner: awesome

Answer (score 11):

As the author of `stackengine` and the provider of a solution on [Subfigures with number inside figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127853/subfigures-with-number-inside-figure), I should be a bit loathe to undercut myself and provide an alternative solution.  But here it is (we're all in it together).  Not nearly as elegant, quite brute force, but it avoids use of the package.

EDITED to remove vestigial part of the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
xxx

\includegraphics[width=5in]{vjbrp}\llap{
  \parbox[b]{4.5in}{(A)\\\rule{0ex}{2.2in}
  }}

yyy
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven! It works with my TeX file after manually fine tune the parameters. This is indeed quite brute force, but so is the answer you provided with `stackengine`, so I still like this one more. However I'm not quite sure why you need `\hspace{4.0in}` after `(a)`. I thought the horizontal and vertical position of `(a)` is tuned by where `4.5in` and `2.2in` is, respectively. Do I get it right?

Comment: @LeoFang, the `\hspace` is vestigial from when I tried a solution without a `\parbox`.  You are right, it should be removed, and I will do so.

Comment: @LeoFang As a follow up, yes, tuning the `4.5in` and `2.2in` will allow horizontal and vertical adjustment, respectively.

Comment: Hi Steven, I found myself confused about the position of the box being overlaid. When using `\llap` to put the label on top of the figure, where is the baseline? I'm asking this because I found when moving the label horizontally to the left, I need to increase rather than decrease the value `4.5in`, which is a little bit counterintuitive. I guess the reason is that it's `\llap` being used, not `\rlap`. By the way, since `\hspace` has no effect here, how do I tune the font size of the label?

Comment: @LeoFang The inset label must be applied *after* the image is rendered (so as not to be covered by it).  Thus, the "cursor" position at the time of rendering is on the right-hand side of the image.  If the image was placed with `\includegraphics`, the baseline of the `\llap` will be the bottom (right-hand corner) of the image.  Thus, increasing the size of the \parbox` moves the inset label to the left.  Likewise, the `\parbox` positioning must be `[b]` to be aligned with that, and the `\rule` commencing on the second line of the parbox lifts the inset upward.  I prefer `stackengine` approach.

Comment: Excellent explanation @Steven! Learnt a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to fill the background of the label (a), (b) and I thought to insert the image inside the tikzpicture-environment as shown here:

[How can I embed an external image within a tikzpicture environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115087/how-can-i-embed-an-external-image-within-a-tikzpicture-environment)

So this is the result:
[image: duck with mark (a) and (b)]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[htbp]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (duck) at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{duck}};
        \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (-2.4,2.1) {(a)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[htbp]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (duck2) at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{duck}};
        \node[align=center,fill=white,draw] at (-2.4,2.1) {(b)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{text}
    \label{duck}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Picture of the duck:
https://www.thoughtco.com/fun-facts-about-ducks-4043231

Comment: I like this approach.