# Text over an inserted picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I put text over a picture (.jpg, say) in a tex document? I have a graphic in my document as a .jpg:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{graphic_1.jpg}
\caption{The map $\phi_0$ }
\end{figure}
```

and I want to label certain parts of it with some mathematical symbols. I'd prefer to do this without tikz, but if someone has a solution using it, then that would be fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Very related: [Put `subfigure` labels inside figures using `subfig` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128844/5764) ([solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128954/5764) is not dependent on the packages mentioned); [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764) (if you're not religiously opposed to [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).