# how to use subfigimg macro and \label

Tags: labels

I'm using the macro subfigimg provided in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/put-subfigure-labels-inside-figures-using-subfig-package#new-answer?newreg=789b838cb6794fa49639600b776288b5) and it is working great.
My problem however is that I would like to \ref to one of the subfigures (which use subfigimg macro) and i have no idea how to do it.

To give an exemple, I would like to do something like that:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1} % http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxutil
\usepackage{graphicx} % http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{10pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-2\baselineskip}{#2}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth}@{}p{0.5\linewidth}}
     \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{(a)}{example-image-a}
     \label{fig:1} &
     \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{(b)}{example-image-b}
     \label{fig:2}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{bla bla bla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which of course does not work and result in ?? instead of a number.
is there a way to work around it? or add option to label in the macro?

I'm really new to tex and to this forum, so please forgive me for being a noob and if I made any mistake.

thanks,
liron

Comment: make small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}.

Comment: Is there any reason for not using the `subcaption` or `subfig` package?

Comment: like I said I'm a noob so i probably missed a lot of options.
I'm not limiting myself to anything.

the final result should be something that:
1. let me put the caption on the figure (which is why i use subfigimg).
2. will let me \ref to any of the subfigimg.

If you have any other idea I will be happy to hear.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I have tried the subcaption pack and it almost does the job. If i use \subcaption{} it is working well, but as i do not want to see the the exra caption  i tried using \subcaption*{} but then I get the same problem again. (getting ?? instead of x.a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build something that is a) a complete MWE and b) does what you want.

Now the labels are displayed like "1.a" and the letters are changed to small letters. If you want to change the formatting of the subfigimg labels change the `\renewcommand*{\thesubfigs}` to your liking, note that this only changes the way the labels are displayed, not those inside the images, for that change the `\alph{subfigs}` in the definition of `\@subfigimg`.

The command `\subfigimg` is available as a starred and an unstarred version. Use the starred version if you use `\caption` in the figure environment prior to your `\subfigimg` and the unstarred one else. This is necessary because we have to increase the `c@figure`-counter temporarily in order to get correct labels if the `\caption` is used after `\subfigimg`.

If you don't need a label on a `\subfigimg` just leave the last argument empty.

I added the possibility to change the position of the label with two additional arguments. They are to be inserted in between the 2 mandatory arguments. The first is inserted with `<horizontal>` (so `<>` as delimiters) and changes the horizontal offset, the second `[vertical]` changes the vertical offset.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{subfigs}[figure]
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigs}{\thefigure.\alph{subfigs}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\subfigimg}{s O{} m D<>{10pt} O{2\baselineskip} m}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
        {\@subfigimg{#2}{#3}{#6}{0}{#4}{#5}}%
        {\@subfigimg{#2}{#3}{#6}{1}{#4}{#5}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@subfigimg}[6]{%
  \bgroup%
  \advance\c@figure by #4%
  \refstepcounter{subfigs}%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax\else%
  \label{#3}%
  \fi%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{#5}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-#6\relax}{(\alph{subfigs})}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
  \egroup%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth}@{}p{0.5\linewidth}}
     \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}{fig:s11}
      &
     \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}{fig:s12}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{bla bla bla}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
See subfigures \ref{fig:s11} and \ref{fig:s12} of figure~\ref{fig:1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{bla bla bla}
  \label{fig:2}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\linewidth}@{}p{0.5\linewidth}}
     \subfigimg*[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}<20pt>[4\baselineskip]{fig:s21}
      &
     \subfigimg*[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}{fig:s22}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
See subfigures \ref{fig:s21} and \ref{fig:s22} of figure~\ref{fig:2}
\end{document}
```

Note that the `subfigs` counter is only reset after the figure counter is increased or when you manually reset it with something like `\setcounter{subfigs}{0}`.

[image]

Comment: ooh wow that is great, anyway to do it so that it will reference \red{fig:s1} as 1.a ? (like he does with subfigure) and just switch the capital letters to small ones?

or is it too much to ask?

thanks a lot...

Comment: @LironLevy the problem is, that the figure counter is increased by the `\caption`-command. Do you always use `\caption` after the `\subfigimg`?

Comment: yes i always use \caption after each figure (like in the example)

Comment: @LironLevy please see my edit.

Comment: WOW... I really have no words to thank you. that is great thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason you used the `standalone` document class rather than the `revtex4-1` class used by the OP?

Comment: @Mico yes there is. I posted my initial answer before the OP posted a complete MWE, so I took the standalone class out of convenience.

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks for your reply; I hadn't been aware that the OP's MWE was late in being posted.

Comment: @Skillmon If I may trouble you a bit more, I have a question.

I use this macro with 2 sizes of graphs thus the location of the caption should be different with each one.
before I just double defined the macro with 2 different names (each had different location for the caption)

will this work in your fix too? , e.g., if i define \newcommand and \NewDocumentCommand two times with 2 different names. or will this ruin something?

Comment: @LironLevy what do you have to change? Maybe I can work something out... Of course you could redefine some stuff or create another macro with another name. But I guess it would be a cleaner solution to enable the changes you need based on one macro.

Comment: sorry i click before finishing the response then couldn't edit...

It will be useful to have the ability to control the x,y offset, i.e., in this line : \rlap{\hspace*{10pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-2\baselineskip}{(\alph{subfigs})}} the 10pt and \baselineskip parmeters... maybe to give the option to inset them for every case... or to pre-define offset option then choose the one you want in each subfugure.

Comment: @LironLevy see my edit. Now there are two additional optional arguments.

Comment: @Skillmon you are the best :)
hopefully more people will find your fix in this post... I'm sure it will be useful.

Comment: @LironLevy I don't think it'll get much attention since most people use the `subcaption` package. And the "best" certainly is [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

Comment: @Skillmon I have a new problem connecting your solution which i posted here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390948/a-problem-using-subfigimg-when-merging-cells

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs the widely-used `subcaption` package, which provides LaTeX environments called `subfigure` and `subtable`. The package also provides lots of options for configuring the formats of all captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure.} % note the '.'
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{First subfigure}\label{fig:small_a}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Second subfigure}\label{fig:small_b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{bla bla bla} \label{fig:big}
\end{figure}

\noindent
Some cross-references to Figure \ref{fig:big} and to Subfigures \ref{fig:small_a} and \ref{fig:small_b}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but i used \subfigimg macro as i want the caption to be on top of the figure. which was what caused my problem.
sorry i wasn't more clear.

But @Skillmon answer just solve the problem.