# Automatically put subcaptions inside picture

Tags: graphics, subcaption, stackengine

I want the same thing as those guys:

- [Put subfigure labels inside figures using subfig package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/put-subfigure-labels-inside-figures-using-subfig-package)
- [Subfigures with number inside figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127853/subfigures-with-number-inside-figure)

But with one minor difference: I don't like the idea to write manually (a) instead of using \subcaption{}. Why? Because by arranging the figures differently later on, I could forget to change the labels accordingly.

Now I did like the idea of using the `stackengine` with its `\stackinset`-command. However, it does not accept `\subcaption{}` as an argument.

So my minimum **non-working** example is as follows (the **non-working** part is the `\subcaption{}` command at its current location):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.96\textwidth}
        \stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{1in}{\subcaption{}}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{example-image-a}}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's not so easy to get rid of the skips, rules, and boxes the `\caption` command would use, I would use `\phantomcaption` instead (for managing the counter and label) and typeset the sub-caption on my own, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.96\textwidth}
        \phantomcaption
        \stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{1in}{(\thesubfigure) Text}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{example-image-a}}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Or if you want to take over the basic formatting options used by the caption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=it,labelsep=endash]{subcaption} % ugly setting, just for demonstration
\usepackage{stackengine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\makesimplesubcaption{\caption@@@make{\caption@fnum{sub\@captype}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.96\textwidth}
        \phantomcaption
        \stackinset{l}{1in}{b}{1in}{\makesimplesubcaption{Text}}{\includegraphics[width=5in]{example-image-a}}
        \label{fig:test}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works indeed as expected. Another way I found doing it is by just referencing using \subref within the \stackinset.

Comment: @AnatraIlDuck it would be great if you could post an example of `using \subref within the \stackinset` as another answer!

Comment: @Gus sorry to disappoint you, I am not using TeX anymore...